# Efficiently match up approximate timestamps in Python

Tags: python

I have two lists of timestamps obtained from two separate sensors, like so:

```
reference = [99999.0, 100000.0, 100001.0,...]

sensor = [99999.8234, 99999.9723, 100000.00123, ... , 100000.9924, 100001.02,...]
```

I would like to efficiently extract the index in `sensor` of values that closest match each value in `reference`.

In the above example `reference[0]` is an earlier timestamp than `sensor[0]` and should therefore be discarded. I would like the code to return `[indexof(100000.00123), indexof(100000.9924)]`.

The list of both reference and sensor timestamps is already sorted.

My attempt is this:

```
sensor_ind = []
ind = 0

for t in reference:
    last_diff = 999999999.99
    while np.fabs(sensor[ind]-t) < last_diff:
        last_diff = np.fabs(sensor[ind]-t)
        ind += 1

    sensor.append(ind)

print sensor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  def closest(l, R):

    from operator import itemgetter

    tupleList = zip(l,  [ abs(x - R) for x in l ])

    closeToR, delta  = sorted(tupleList, key=itemgetter(1)).pop(0)

    return closeToR  

for el in reference:
    print(closest(sensor,el))

99999.8234
100000.00123
100000.9924
```

of use  bisect

you can you bisect module, it will find for 100001.0 in reference 
    index 3 in sensor that is 100000.9924

[bisect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html?highlight=bisect#module-bisect)

```
def get_match(list_, el):
    import bisect

    i = bisect.bisect_left(list_, el)

    if i == len(list_):
        return i - 1
    elif list_[i] == el:
        return i
    elif i > 0:
        j = i - 1

        if list_[i] - el > el - list_[j]:
            return j
    return

reference = [99999.0, 100000.0, 100001.0]

sensor = [99999.8234, 99999.9723, 100000.00123, 100000.9924, 100001.02]

for el in reference:
    print(get_match(sensor,el))

None
None
3
```